# Interleave float coordinates without error

Tags: python, encoding, coordinates, z-order-curve, space-filling-curve

I wonder how I can interleave float coordinates. [This website](https://www.forceflow.be/2013/10/07/morton-encodingdecoding-through-bit-interleaving-implementations/) describes how to do the interleaving part, but it is only for integers.

I have tried following method:

> lat = 5.01, lng = 6.01
>
> newLat = (5.01+90) * 100
>
> newLng = (6.01+180) * 100

But it appears to not have the right bit sequence. Does someone know of a better way to represent lat and lng as a 32 bit sequence?

Comment: What does "not have the right bit sequence" mean?  What you tried looks valid, although it's only going to give you a resolution of 1/100 degree, which may be too coarse for your purposes (it's nowhere near accurate enough to identify a particular house, for example).  You should choose a multiplicative factor such that the largest possible float value turns into an integer that is as close as possible to the maximum value the bit interleaving code can handle.

Comment: And how can I do that? You mean I should multiply by 2^16 if I am using 16 bits?

Take a look at this one: https://www.slideshare.net/CCR_Inc/geomesa-on-spark-sql-extracting-location-intelligence-from-data?fbclid=IwAR1G4pBl36buEMbCYKvD6F0gcK47WINXzV9j7N_EQTM4VPYMLspMf4rIHTE

I tried to do the same, but end up with something weird...

Comment: No, multiplying by 2^16 would cause an overflow of a 16-bit integer, since your float values can be greater than 1.  182 might work - that turns 360.0 into 65520, which barely fits.

Comment: So what should the formula look like?